# Hide item of QTreeView when item gets created

Tags: qt

I have an application which contains two views of the same model: a `QTreeView` and `QTableView`. For some specific nested items say `PeakItem`, derived from `QStandardItem`, I would like them to be hidden in the `QTreeView` but showed in the `QTableView`. To do so, I did the following:

```
void PeakItem::setData(const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    emitDataChanged();
}
```

and when my model is created I add the following signal/slot connection

```
connect(ui->treeView->model(),SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)),ui->treeView,SLOT(addNewItem(QModelIndex)));
```

Debugging my code, the `PeakItem::SetData` is actually called but the signal does not seem to be fired or at least is not caught by the tree view as I would expect. Would you have any idea about what I did wrong ?

Comment: You might check what `QObject::connect()` function call returns, i.e. `bool ok = connect(ui->treeView->model(),SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)),ui->treeView,SLOT(addNewItem(QModelIndex)));`

Comment: It returns `true`. In fact, I think that I found the reason why the signal is not caught but not the solution. Being a nested sub-item, once constructed, my `PeakItem` is not yet bound to the model. Indeed, it is only when it is added to its parent item using `appendRow` which is in turn appended to the model that the connection is made to the model. And in such case, I do not know how to proceed

Comment: On a side note you should probably be using the new [signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_QObject_member).

Comment: you right I should get rid of the old styled syntax.

Comment: If you're programatically trying to hide an item in a view, that looks like you're not using Qt's model/view framework correctly. Did you consider using a filter (say a `QSortFilterProxyModel`) between your shared model and your QTreeView? Then you could simply return `false` in `filterAcceptsRow()` if the row is a `PeakItem`.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Indeed, that is probably the way to go. I will give a try.